# How to draw stacked /vastellated bar charts

Tags: pgfplots

i want to draw a chart like this (Chart / Image taken from [here](http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fjunkcharts.typepad.com%2F.a%2F6a00d8341e992c53ef0120a55387f7970c-pi&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fjunkcharts.typepad.com%2Fjunk_charts%2Fcompound_plots%2Fpage%2F2%2F&h=1778&w=663&tbnid=eHPSGDXBOeenTM%3A&zoom=1&docid=6oRbXRi9MT6ZWM&ei=mI-xU8H4DOTA7Ab4pIGICg&tbm=isch&client=firefox-a&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=554&page=1&start=0&ndsp=25&ved=0CHAQrQMwGA)):

[image]

First of all: How is this type of diagram called? By searching "stacked bar chart" in google, I cannot find charts like this. My second question is if it is possible to dras such a chart with pgfplots (not necessarily identical to the chart given above).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmm, similar to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27733/creating-a-highly-customized-barchart), but not given a name there either.

Comment: Randall Monroe does this [sort of thing](http://www.xkcd.com/radiation/) well.  I think the key is to be clear about the size of your unit. But I'll leave others to asnwer your specific question about pgfplots.